# Hosting ASP.NET MVC 3 application using MongoDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb, cloud

I'd like to hear if any of you had experiences developing and hosting such an application?

What do you think about combining the two? Is there a way to host it somewhere in cloud (Azure, Amazon...)? What resources (tools, drivers, documentation) have you used for development?

Thanks! :)

Comment: few weeks later, what did you choose ? I'm in the same process of finding a not-too-expensive way of hosting MVC3 apps and MongoDB. Do you have a feedback on your experience ? thx: PS: I'm targeting a small web application that can potentially grows. At begining, I can't afford a dedicated server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a couple of applications with asp.net mvc 3 and mongodb.

For the asp.net mvc app regular windows hosting.
For the mongodb i am using unix hosting (since it cost in several times lower than windows hosting).

Also you may need:

1. Official c# driver for mongodb: [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver)
2. Official driver documentation: [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center)
3. Great ui tool (like management studio for sql server) for mongodb: [mongovue](http://www.mongovue.com/)
4. And [mongodb manual](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Manual) ;)

That's all. Hope this help you quickly start development.

> What do you think about combining the
>   two?

Mongodb good fit for many web applications, it can be easy used with asp.net mvc 3 since exists nice driver for c# that contatins all latest features.

Comment: Thanks! :) What about the performance and speed of transactions, since application and database are not on the same server?

Comment: @Nebo: They shoud be in the same local network and with performance everything will be okay.

Comment: What about hosting such an application in cloud? Do you have any experience with Azure or Amazon cloud, quality, price...?

Comment: @Nebo: No, i haven't such exp.

Comment: @Andrew Orsich: you said `shoud be in the same local network`... Do you have an hosting provider to recommend which provides this ability, to mix Minux host and MVC host ?

Comment: anyone know of any asp.net hosting providers that support full trust or NetSocketPermission so it the app can use remote mongodb server?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently developed a small application using ASP.NET and MongoDB.  I hosted the application on cheap shared Windows hosting @ www.FreeWindHosting.com and hosted the db at www.MongoLabs.com.

I will be writing a small backup service to back up my free MongoLab db to Amazon S3, but otherwise this setup works remarkably well, even with several "Handshakes" between the application and MomgoLab every request.